# How to remove the caption in gallery caption module?

Tags: media

I'm using Gallery formatter, how to remove the caption? But I want to leave the title and alt parameters.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use css `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy file galleryformatter.tpl.php from Gallery formatter module to your folder theme. And remove some code line 28->35

```
<?php if (!empty($data['title']) || !empty($data['alt'])): ?>
            <div class="panel-overlay">
              <div class="overlay-inner">
                <?php if ($data['alt']): ?><h4><?php print $data['alt']; ?></h4><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($data['title']): ?><h3><?php print $data['title']; ?></h3><?php endif; ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php endif; ?>
```

And clear cache.